# merging a system partition with a partition preceding it

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, formatting, windows-10-preview

My hard drive is 500 Gb,

I partitioned it with 400gb for windows 7 and 100gb for Windows 10,

however I am in need of a bit more space, thus I shrank 50gb from the windwos 7 partition,

besides formatting and reinstalling Windows 10 (as a last option), how else can I expand the partition while keeping the current data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fond a solution,

using AOMEI Partition Manager, solved my problem

For those who are insterested